# openbox - How to switch user without logout?

Tags: debian, openbox, lightdm

I'm using debian 8.3 jessie stable with openbox, fbpanel, lightdm. When I'm in openbox session, I do not find an option to switch user without logging out the current user.

How can I switch user from openbox without logging out from current user session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with the following command for lightdm:

```
/usr/bin/dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```